# Jquery selector for an input with a specific name and inside a specific form

Tags: jquery, forms, input, selector

I want to select an input with a **name "pass"** which is inside a form with the **id "idreg"**.

The idea is not to use an id in this input (obviously this would simplify what I want to do) and I can't select by the name because I have, in another form, a input with the name "pass".

Comment: `$('#idreg [name="pass"]')`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [jQuery attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

It selects the element that have the specified attribute with the given value, exactly.

```
$('#idreg [name="pass"]')
```

should work fine.